# How to set a specified range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a pivot table in VBA and am trying to set the correct range. I am using last column and last row to capture all possible values if i ever need to edit the original data table. That being said, my table starts at row 7, and when i change my code to reflect that, it only captures the first column.

```
lr = dsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lc = dsheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set prange = dsheet.Cells(7, 1).Resize(lr, lc)
```

when i have dsheet.cells(7,1) setup, it picks the correct row but it only selects A column (my table spans many columns and rows)

when i have dsheet.cells(1,1,) setup, i can't make a pivot table because there are no headers for the table.

of course another option is to just delete the unnecessary rows, but i'd rather just keep it the way it is and add on to it.

I'd like my output to be where i can select Row 7, go all the way down to the last row, and all the way over to the last column

Comment: ```set prange = dsheet.range(dsheet.cells(7,1), dsheet.cells(lr, lc))```

Comment: You might also need `lc = dsheet.Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`.

Comment: @SJR thanks for your response, this code works great

Comment: Now someone just needs to post the solution and mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many different ways, this code right here is the one that works consistently and does not require much effort to edit if need be:

```
lr = dsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lc = dsheet.Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set prange = dsheet.Cells(7, 1).Resize(lr, lc)
```